# Django clean_fields and mandatory field

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my models.py I have a field:

```
content_type = models.CharField(u"Content type", max_length=20)
```

As you can see it is mandatory. But I want to assign it a value automatically, so I did:

```
def clean_fields(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    self.content_type = "Whatever"
```

But in the admin of Django I get a validation error telling me that this field is required. However when I look at the content of kwargs, I get:

```
{'exclude': ['id', 'created_on', 'modified_on', 'content_type', 'content_ptr']}
```

So my questions are:
1) Why does this field appear in the 'exclude' list?
2) Why does Django raises this validation error?

Comment: In case you were wondering, I deleted my answer since I realised you were referring to [`clean_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean_fields) on the model rather than the forms clean methods..

Comment: Are you using a model form with your model at all?.. how do you render your model?

Comment: Are you going to fill that model just from admin panel?

Comment: For the moment I only render it in the admin panel. But like it is said in the answer below, clean_fields shouldn't be used for this. However I still don't understand why it appears in the exclude list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a value automatically to your model like this.

```
class ModelName(models.Model)    
    content_type = models.CharField(u"Content type", max_length=20)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.set_content_type()
        super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_content_type(self):
         self.content_type = 'Whatever'
         self.save()
```

In this way whenever an instance of that model will be created, that field will automatically get value.
clean_field is used to validate form fields.